# trigeome-Tree question: using calculus

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

(Like my title?)

I have had a test a few days ago about calculus, which had a problem like this:

a tree is 20 feet away. a man 5 feet tall looks at a $50°$ angle to see the top. if $\cos 50\approx 0.9649$, How tall is the tree?

This is very confusing. I have a paper and i figured out all the math. This is how:

since The following is true:

$$ \text{if $\theta$ is angle}\\
\text{and x, y, and z are measures whereas}\\
x^2+y^2=z^2 \text{or} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z\\
\text{and x is adjacent then} \\
\sin \theta=\frac{y}{z}\\
\cos \theta=\frac{x}{z}\\
\tan \theta=\frac{y}{x}\\
\csc \theta=\frac{z}{y}\\
\sec \theta=\frac{z}{x}\\
\cot \theta=\frac{x}{y}\\
$$
i spent 10 minutes calculating them by hand(i may be a bit off)
$$
\sin 50=0.9649\\
\cos 50=0.642\\
\tan 50=1.192\\
\csc 50=1.305\\
\sec 50=1.554\\
\cot 50=0.839\\
$$

So i thought for a bit and used them, getting a variety of results. I multiplied x by each of them, but they all seemed like the correct one(save for sin and cos, the hypotenuse is ALWAYS larger than the sides) so i ended up putting an answer in at random ($(x\times\csc 50)+5$)and hoping for the best. (This was an on-line test designed to evaluate your knowledge, mind you i'm only in 7th grade) and i got the question wrong. How would i go about doing this?

(p.s:i put in +5 ft because the eyes are 5 ft above the ground)

Comment: ...but neither $\sin(50^o)$ nor $\cos(50^o)$ is near $0.9649$?

Comment: *checks calculator* in fact, $\sin(50)\approx .7660$, $\cos(50) \approx .6428$

Comment: Ah, I see now, the the cosine of $50$ _radians_ is about .9649

Comment: I'm impressed that seventh graders like you try out more advanced questions and raise important points.  There's nothing wrong with inquisition or curiosity - I just wish kids had more of it!

Comment: @bjcolby15 I'm not your average 7th grader.

Answer (score 1):

One small problem...the angle you're given is in degrees - however, you calculated the cosine of 50 as 50 *radians.*

Since the person is standing 20 feet away from the top of the tree (adjacent) the height of the tree is $20 \tan 50°$ or $23.84 \text { ft}.$

EDIT: The previous answer I gave, $31.11 \text { ft}$, is for the angle of elevation as the viewer sees the tree, which is $20 \over {\cos 50°}$.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: *facepalm* sorry about that....

Comment: No apologies needed.  There are times that I don't know my own name.

Comment: Dividing $20$ by $\cos 50^\circ$ gives the distance from the man's eyes to the top of the tree, not the height of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

So if observer is $20$ ft from the base of the tree, you want to compute $20\tan(50^o) \approx 23.84$, to which we add $5$ feet to account for the height of the observer for a final height of $28.84$ feet.

The reason for choosing $\tan$ is that you know distance to the base of the tree (likely, that's the easier thing to measure), which is the leg of the right triangle adjacent to the known angle, and $\tan$ encodes the ratio of opposite side to adjacent side: $$\text{adjacent}\times\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \text{opposite}$$

Answer (score 0):

When the problem says the tree is $20$ feet away, I think that means
the man would have to walk $20$ feet to reach the base of the tree.
When it says the man is $5$ feet tall I assume it means how high his eyes are above the ground. (Otherwise we would have to guess about that part.)

I also assume the tree trunk is straight up and down and that the ground between the man and the tree is level. (Not always true in real life.)

So there is a straight, level line segment $20$ feet long from the man's eyes to a spot on the trunk $5$ feet up from the ground. The trunk goes up perpendicularly from that point to the top of the tree, so that's another line segment and we now have two legs of a right triangle. 
The hypotenuse is the line of sight from the man's eyes to the top of the tree.
There is a $50$ degree angle at the vertex where the man's eyes are.

The formulas you wrote assume $x$ is the adjacent leg,
so $x = 20$ (the line segment from the eyes to the point on the tree $5$ feet from the ground). The opposite leg $y$ is the part of the tree from $5$ feet to the top, and the hypotenuse is $z.$
The height of the tree (which you really want in the end)
is $5+y$ (you were right about adding $5$).

So we have $x=20$ and we want $y.$
A good way to do this is to multiply $x$ by $\frac yx,$
because $x \times \frac yx = y.$
Look for $\frac yx$ in your list of formulas; 
see that $\tan\theta = \frac yx.$
So $\frac yx = \tan \theta = \tan 50^\circ \approx 1.192,$
so $y = x \times \tan 50^\circ \approx 20 \times 1.192 = 23.84.$

Basically, to apply trigonometry to a problem like this you need a good picture of what is going on so you can identify the triangle(s) in it and 
identify which of the trigonometric formulas correctly identify the
relationships between the things you know and the things you want to know.